# Huffman code with lookup table

Tags: c++

I have read an article on Internet and know that the natural way of decoding by traversing from root but I want to do it faster with a lookup table.

After reading, I still cannot get the points.

ex:

```
input:"abcdaabaaabaaa"
code   data
0      a
10     b
110    c
111    d
```

The article says that due to variable length, it determine the length by taking a bit of string of
max code length and use it as index.

```
output:"010110111001000010000"
Index    Index(binary)    Code    Bits required
0        000              a       1
1        001              a       1
2        010              a       1
3        011              a       1
4        100              b       2
5        101              b       2
6        110              c       3
7        111              d       3
```

My questions are:

1. What does it means `due to variable length, it determine the length by taking a bit of string of
   max code length`? How to determine the length?
2. How to generate the lookup table and how to use it? What is the algorithm behind?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your example, the maximum code length is 3 bits. So you take the first 3 bits from your stream (010) and use that to index the table. This gives code, 'a' and bits = 1. You consume 1 bit from your input stream, output the code, and carry on. On the second go around you will get (101), which indexes as 'b' and 2 bits, etc.

To build the table, make it as large as 1 << max_code_length, and fill in details as if you are decoding the index as a huffman code. If you look at your example all the indices which begin '0' are a, indices beginning '10' are b, and so on.